# What's happened to my <p> alignments?

Tags: css

I would like my ((#banner_citrus_web_design p {)) `<p>` alignments in the center but it has a weird indent for some reason. Check my code and see what's happening please?

The weird indent is happening to my paragraph element and really want the paragraph element to sit smack back in the center.

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 }

body {
 background: #E6E6E6;
 }
 
#head_wrapper {
 background:#000;
 }
 
#head_wrapper h1 {
 display: inline; 
 float: left; 
 margin: -3px 20px 20px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Pacifico';
 font-weight:100;
 }

#head_wrapper #nav_ul {
 text-align: right;
 }
 
#head_wrapper #nav_ul li {
 list-style-type:none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 15px 15px 20px;
 }
 
#head_wrapper #nav_ul li a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 }
 
#head_wrapper #nav_ul li #link_hover:hover {
 background:#FF9933;
 border-radius:10%;
 }
 
#banner_citrus_web_design {
 background:#000;
 height:400px;
 }

#banner_citrus_web_design p {
 color:gray;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Citrus</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header id="head_wrapper">
   <h1>Citrus</h1>
    <nav id="nav_bar">
     <ul id="nav_ul">
      <li>
       <div id="link_hover">
        <a href="#">
         Home
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div id="link_hover">
        <a href="#">
         Services
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div id="link_hover">
        <a href="#">
         Work
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div id="link_hover">
        <a href="#">
         Contact
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  <section id="banner_citrus_web_design">
   <p>CITRUS WEB DEVELOPMENT</p>
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but we are not code reviewers.. You should narrow it down by analyzing your own code, and identifying a possible issue, instead of just posting te entire code for us to parse it.

Comment: I posted the whole code because it's a mistake within the other margins - which ive just realied. Therefore, you are able to review the whole CSS and see where the margins are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `clear:both;` in `#banner_citrus_web_design {`

Comment: Wait!!! It works - meaning it changes the alignment, but the margin from '* { margin:0; } has now decided to not direct toward the #banner_citrus_web_design statement.

Comment: that happens due to the float: left; in `#head_wrapper h1`.., and actually the text inside p tag is struck in the right side of the h1 tag.. .. so need to clear it

Comment: This then changes the alignment of the title and the nav bar!!??

Comment: clearing the section #banner_citrus_web_design dosent change alignment

Comment: another method is to add float and width to the header `#head_wrapper`  -  `float: left;   width: 100%; `

Answer (score 0):

You should use "text-align: center;" at the place of "margin:0 auto;" for a `<p>`tag.

```
* {
margin:0;
}

body {
background: #E6E6E6;
}

#head_wrapper {
background:#000;
}

#head_wrapper h1 {
display: inline; 
float: left; 
margin: -3px 20px 20px;
color: white;
font-family: 'Pacifico';
font-weight:100;
}

#head_wrapper #nav_ul {
text-align: right;
}

#head_wrapper #nav_ul li {
list-style-type:none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 15px 15px 20px;
}

#head_wrapper #nav_ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#head_wrapper #nav_ul li #link_hover:hover {
background:#FF9933;
border-radius:10%;
}

#banner_citrus_web_design {
background:#000;
height:400px;
}

#banner_citrus_web_design p {
color:gray;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: replace your hole css by the above css this will align "CITRUS WEB DEVELOPMENT" in center

Comment: Add " text-align: center;"  in #banner_citrus_web_design p {